# How can PDO not return a row which pg_query() does?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, pg-query

I had a table with a bigserial PK, one character varying FK and a bigint FK and a unique constraint on these FKs, a character varying NOT NULL and two nullable smallints.

All of this was running in a VM with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, PHP 5.5.9 and PostgreSQL 9.3 and all other packages from the distribution.

I did

```
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

and

```
$r = pg_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table");
pg_fetch_all($r)
```

The latter returned all rows while the former returned all rows except for one.

I tried to select that very row as well, and while the `pg_*()` functions worked as expected, PDO did not return any row.

To make it even stranger, the discrepancy only emerged in PHP-FPM with lighttpd 1.4.33, but not when run with PHP CLI in a shell.

How can that be?
Did anyone else encounter a similar situation?
And how can I be sure that PDO will not fail me again?

I even tried rebooting the VM and restarted PostgreSQL, but the results did not change.

Sadly, I do not have a backup of this stuff because I had to get things working ASAP, so I deleted that mysterious row and replaced it with a new one, identical in all columns except for the PK.

The new row was returned properly by both.

Comment: What is the structure of your primary key ?

Comment: What do you mean by structure? It is a scalar bigserial.

Comment: I asked to see if you had a composite primary key. Anyway, using native pgsql API in place of PDO will grant you with (almost) all Pg's functionalities and better performances.

Comment: Yes, the specific APIs are probably always faster, but some ORMs only support PDO, and PDO makes it easier to switch between databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, PostgreSQL may yield confusing and inconsistent results when its index gets corrupted.

In this case, just recreate the index and check if it fixes your problem.